# Get positions for NAs only in the "middle" of a matrix column

Tags: r

I want to obtain an index that refers to the positions of NA values in a matrix where the index is true if a given cell is NA and there is at least one non-NA value before and after it in the column. For example, given the following matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA    1   NA    1
[2,]    1   NA   NA    2
[3,]   NA    2   NA    3
```

the only value of the index that comes back TRUE should be [2,2].

Is there a compact expression for what I want to do? If I had to I could loop through columns and use something like `min(which(!is.na(x[,i])))` to find the first non-NA value in each column, and then set all values before that to FALSE (and the same for all values after the max). This way I would not select leading and trailing NA values. But this seems a bit messy, so I'm wondering if there is a cleaner expression that does this without loops.

**EDIT** To be valid an NA value only needs to have a non-NA value before and after it somewhere within the column, but not necessarily adjacent to it. For instance, if a column was defined by c(NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA), the NA's I want to find would be the ones at positions 3, 4, and 5, as these are enclosed by non-NA values.

Comment: [2,3] should not be returned also?

Comment: daroczig - no, because there is no non-NA value before and after it in the column.

Comment: thank you, I should have read your question more thoughtfully. I tried to make up a vectorized answer based on your details, I hope it could work for your.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't tested this very thoroughly, but it does work on the test case:

```
z <- matrix(c(NA,1,NA,1,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3),ncol=4)
isNA <- is.na(z)
# Vertical index which increments at non-NA entries, counting top-to-bottom:
nonNA_idx.tb <- apply(!isNA, 2, cumsum)
# Vertical index which increments at non-NA entries, counting bottom-to-top:
nonNA_idx.bt <- apply(!isNA, 2, function(x) { rev(cumsum(rev(x))) })
which(isNA & nonNA_idx.tb>0 & nonNA_idx.bt>0, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

(PS -- I think it's pretty cute, but I'm biased)

Comment: You need to explain the cleverness. x1 is an indexing sequence which increments at non-NA entries, counting top-to-bottom. x2 is the same, counting backward (bottom-to-top). They are only both nonzero at internal entries enclosed by non-NAs on both top and bottom, hence their non-NA indices counting in both directions are >0. Finally gate that with a & to filter out just the internal NAs. Can you rename x1,x2 to be more intuitive? nonNA_idx.tb, nonNA_idx.bt perhaps?

Comment: @smci, if you have the necessary reputation (and it looks like you do -- 2K), feel free to edit ...

Answer (score 1):

```
m <- matrix(c(NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3), ncol= 4)

matmain <- is.na(m)
matprev <- rbind(FALSE, head(!matmain, -1))
matnext <- rbind(tail(!matmain, -1), FALSE)

which(matmain & (matprev | matnext), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

I interpreted the question slightly differently. When you say before and after in the column, do you mean immediately before and after, or anywhere before and after? With the following test matrix, we have [2,1] [3,1] and [2,2], but what about [2,3]?

```
m <- matrix(c(1, NA, NA, 5, 1, NA, 3, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 5), ncol= 4)
```

Comment: Your answer and mine are complementary, I think (different interpretations of the question)

Comment: Actually on closer reading, I think I've got it wrong, because my version returns more than [2, 2]. Change the `|` in the last line to `&` and it returns only [2, 2], but I think he's looking for a cumulative NA count. However, a useful question because I never before grasped how to refer to nearby rows and columns without using a for loop.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had meant an NA for which there is a non-NA value SOMEWHERE before or after it in the column, but not necessarily adjacent to it. For instance, if you had input matrix matrix(c(NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4),ncol=4), you would only want to return [2,2] and [2,3]. Nonetheless, your code certainly offers an interesting approach to the related problem of dealing with NAs for which there must be an adjacent non-NA value.

Answer (score 1):

```
pts <- sample(c(1:10,NA), size = 100, replace = T)

mat <- matrix(pts, ncol = 10)

which(is.na(mat), arr.ind = T)
```